# Ayuda Con el placeHolder y label Float

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver tienen la propiedad PlaceHolder, ademas de esta le agregue tambien un label Flotante, que lo que hace esque al yo seleccionar el TextBox se coloca como titulo, como se ve en la siguiente Imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aqui todo bien, el probema esta cuando dejo ese campo vacio y teniendo este la clase  Required que me valida que los campos no queden vacios, me muestra lo siguiente (Que esta bn que lo haga):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando selecciono nuevamente el texbox para introducior datos, los textos se "Chocan", como se ve a continuacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber como puedo evitar eso. Voy a copiarr el codigo JQuery donde se supone que esta la validacion, el problema es que no lo encuentro o mejor dicho, no se como hacerlo, Espero alguien pueda ayudarme:

```js
/*! jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.13.0 - 7/1/2014
 * http://jqueryvalidation.org/
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Jörn Zaefferer; Licensed MIT */
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):a(jQuery)}(function(a){a.extend(a.fn,{validate:function(b){if(!this.length)return void(b&&b.debug&&window.console&&console.warn("Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing."));var c=a.data(this[0],"validator");return c?c:(this.attr("novalidate","novalidate"),c=new a.validator(b,this[0]),a.data(this[0],"validator",c),c.settings.onsubmit&&(this.validateDelegate(":submit","click",function(b){c.settings.submitHandler&&(c.submitButton=b.target),a(b.target).hasClass("cancel")&&(c.cancelSubmit=!0),void 0!==a(b.target).attr("formnovalidate")&&(c.cancelSubmit=!0)}),this.submit(function(b){function d(){var d;return c.settings.submitHandler?(c.submitButton&&(d=a("<input type='hidden'/>").attr("name",c.submitButton.name).val(a(c.submitButton).val()).appendTo(c.currentForm)),c.settings.submitHandler.call(c,c.currentForm,b),c.submitButton&&d.remove(),!1):!0}return c.settings.debug&&b.preventDefault(),c.cancelSubmit?(c.cancelSubmit=!1,d()):c.form()?c.pendingRequest?(c.formSubmitted=!0,!1):d():(c.focusInvalid(),!1)})),c)},valid:function(){var b,c;return a(this[0]).is("form")?b=this.validate().form():(b=!0,c=a(this[0].form).validate(),this.each(function(){b=c.element(this)&&b})),b},removeAttrs:function(b){var c={},d=this;return a.each(b.split(/\s/),function(a,b){c[b]=d.attr(b),d.removeAttr(b)}),c},rules:function(b,c){var d,e,f,g,h,i,j=this[0];if(b)switch(d=a.data(j.form,"validator").settings,e=d.rules,f=a.validator.staticRules(j),b){case"add":a.extend(f,a.validator.normalizeRule(c)),delete f.messages,e[j.name]=f,c.messages&&(d.messages[j.name]=a.extend(d.messages[j.name],c.messages));break;case"remove":return c?(i={},a.each(c.split(/\s/),function(b,c){i[c]=f[c],delete f[c],"required"===c&&a(j).removeAttr("aria-required")}),i):(delete e[j.name],f)}return g=a.validator.normalizeRules(a.extend({},a.validator.classRules(j),a.validator.attributeRules(j),a.validator.dataRules(j),a.validator.staticRules(j)),j),g.required&&(h=g.required,delete g.required,g=a.extend({required:h},g),a(j).attr("aria-required","true")),g.remote&&(h=g.remote,delete g.remote,g=a.extend(g,{remote:h})),g}}),a.extend(a.expr[":"],{blank:function(b){return!a.trim(""+a(b).val())},filled:function(b){return!!a.trim(""+a(b).val())},unchecked:function(b){return!a(b).prop("checked")}}),a.validator=function(b,c){this.settings=a.extend(!0,{},a.validator.defaults,b),this.currentForm=c,this.init()},a.validator.format=function(b,c){return 1===arguments.length?function(){var c=a.makeArray(arguments);return c.unshift(b),a.validator.format.apply(this,c)}:(arguments.length>2&&c.constructor!==Array&&(c=a.makeArray(arguments).slice(1)),c.constructor!==Array&&(c=[c]),a.each(c,function(a,c){b=b.replace(new RegExp("\\{"+a+"\\}","g"),function(){return c})}),b)},a.extend(a.validator,{defaults:{messages:{},groups:{},rules:{},errorClass:"error",validClass:"valid",errorElement:"label",focusInvalid:!0,errorContainer:a([]),errorLabelContainer:a([]),onsubmit:!0,ignore:":hidden",ignoreTitle:!1,onfocusin:function(a){this.lastActive=a,this.settings.focusCleanup&&!this.blockFocusCleanup&&(this.settings.unhighlight&&this.settings.unhighlight.call(this,a,this.settings.errorClass,this.settings.validClass),this.hideThese(this.errorsFor(a)))},onfocusout:function(a){this.checkable(a)||!(a.name in this.submitted)&&this.optional(a)||this.element(a)},onkeyup:function(a,b){(9!==b.which||""!==this.elementValue(a))&&(a.name in this.submitted||a===this.lastElement)&&this.element(a)},onclick:function(a){a.name in this.submitted?this.element(a):a.parentNode.name in this.submitted&&this.element(a.parentNode)},highlight:function(b,c,d){"radio"===b.type?this.findByName(b.name).addClass(c).removeClass(d):a(b).addClass(c).removeClass(d)},unhighlight:function(b,c,d){"radio"===b.type?this.findByName(b.name).removeClass(c).addClass(d):a(b).removeClass(c).addClass(d)}},setDefaults:function(b){a.extend(a.validator.defaults,b)},messages:{required:"Este campo es requerido.",remote:"Please fix this field.",email:"Ingrese una dirección e-mail válida",direccion:"Ingrese una dirección válida",url:"Please enter a valid URL.",date:"Please enter a valid date.",dateISO:"Please enter a valid date ( ISO ).",number:"Por favor ingrese un número válido",texto:"Ingrese solo letras",digits:"Ingrese solo números.",creditcard:"Please enter a valid credit card number.",equalTo:"El valor no corresponde",maxlength:a.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),minlength:a.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),rangelength:a.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),range:a.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),max:a.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),min:a.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")},autoCreateRanges:!1,prototype:{init:function(){function b(b){var c=a.data(this[0].form,"validator"),d="on"+b.type.replace(/^validate/,""),e=c.settings;e[d]&&!this.is(e.ignore)&&e[d].call(c,this[0],b)}this.labelContainer=a(this.settings.errorLabelContainer),this.errorContext=this.labelContainer.length&&this.labelContainer||a(this.currentForm),this.containers=a(this.settings.errorContainer).add(this.settings.errorLabelContainer),this.submitted={},this.valueCache={},this.pendingRequest=0,this.pending={},this.invalid={},this.reset();var c,d=this.groups={};a.each(this.settings.groups,function(b,c){"string"==typeof c&&(c=c.split(/\s/)),a.each(c,function(a,c){d[c]=b})}),c=this.settings.rules,a.each(c,function(b,d){c[b]=a.validator.normalizeRule(d)}),a(this.currentForm).validateDelegate(":text, [type='password'], [type='file'], select, textarea, [type='number'], [type='search'] ,[type='tel'], [type='url'], [type='email'], [type='datetime'], [type='date'], [type='month'], [type='week'], [type='time'], [type='datetime-local'], [type='range'], [type='color'], [type='radio'], [type='checkbox']","focusin focusout keyup",b).validateDelegate("select, option, [type='radio'], [type='checkbox']","click",b),this.settings.invalidHandler&&a(this.currentForm).bind("invalid-form.validate",this.settings.invalidHandler),a(this.currentForm).find("[required], [data-rule-required], .required").attr("aria-required","true")},form:function(){return this.checkForm(),a.extend(this.submitted,this.errorMap),this.invalid=a.extend({},this.errorMap),this.valid()||a(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form",[this]),this.showErrors(),this.valid()},checkForm:function(){this.prepareForm();for(var a=0,b=this.currentElements=this.elements();b[a];a++)this.check(b[a]);return this.valid()},element:function(b){var c=this.clean(b),d=this.validationTargetFor(c),e=!0;return this.lastElement=d,void 0===d?delete this.invalid[c.name]:(this.prepareElement(d),this.currentElements=a(d),e=this.check(d)!==!1,e?delete this.invalid[d.name]:this.invalid[d.name]=!0),a(b).attr("aria-invalid",!e),this.numberOfInvalids()||(this.toHide=this.toHide.add(this.containers)),this.showErrors(),e},showErrors:function(b){if(b){a.extend(this.errorMap,b),this.errorList=[];for(var c in b)this.errorList.push({message:b[c],element:this.findByName(c)[0]});this.successList=a.grep(this.successList,function(a){return!(a.name in b)})}this.settings.showErrors?this.settings.showErrors.call(this,this.errorMap,this.errorList):this.defaultShowErrors()},resetForm:function(){a.fn.resetForm&&a(this.currentForm).resetForm(),this.submitted={},this.lastElement=null,this.prepareForm(),this.hideErrors(),this.elements().removeClass(this.settings.errorClass).removeData("previousValue").removeAttr("aria-invalid")},numberOfInvalids:function(){return this.objectLength(this.invalid)},objectLength:function(a){var b,c=0;for(b in a)c++;return c},hideErrors:function(){this.hideThese(this.toHide)},hideThese:function(a){a.not(this.containers).text(""),this.addWrapper(a).hide()},valid:function(){return 0===this.size()},size:function(){return this.errorList.length},focusInvalid:function(){if(this.settings.focusInvalid)try{a(this.findLastActive()||this.errorList.length&&this.errorList[0].element||[]).filter(":visible").focus().trigger("focusin")}catch(b){}},findLastActive:function(){var b=this.lastActive;return b&&1===a.grep(this.errorList,function(a){return a.element.name===b.name}).length&&b},elements:function(){var b=this,c={};return a(this.currentForm).find("input, select, textarea").not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]").not(this.settings.ignore).filter(function(){return!this.name&&b.settings.debug&&window.console&&console.error("%o has no name assigned",this),this.name in c||!b.objectLength(a(this).rules())?!1:(c[this.name]=!0,!0)})},clean:function(b){return a(b)[0]},errors:function(){var b=this.settings.errorClass.split(" ").join(".");return a(this.settings.errorElement+"."+b,this.errorContext)},reset:function(){this.successList=[],this.errorList=[],this.errorMap={},this.toShow=a([]),this.toHide=a([]),this.currentElements=a([])},prepareForm:function(){this.reset(),this.toHide=this.errors().add(this.containers)},prepareElement:function(a){this.reset(),this.toHide=this.errorsFor(a)},elementValue:function(b){var c,d=a(b),e=b.type;return"radio"===e||"checkbox"===e?a("input[name='"+b.name+"']:checked").val():"number"===e&&"undefined"!=typeof b.validity?b.validity.badInput?!1:d.val():(c=d.val(),"string"==typeof c?c.replace(/\r/g,""):c)},check:function(b){b=this.validationTargetFor(this.clean(b));var c,d,e,f=a(b).rules(),g=a.map(f,function(a,b){return b}).length,h=!1,i=this.elementValue(b);for(d in f){e={method:d,parameters:f[d]};try{if(c=a.validator.methods[d].call(this,i,b,e.parameters),"dependency-mismatch"===c&&1===g){h=!0;continue}if(h=!1,"pending"===c)return void(this.toHide=this.toHide.not(this.errorsFor(b)));if(!c)return this.formatAndAdd(b,e),!1}catch(j){throw this.settings.debug&&window.console&&console.log("Exception occurred when checking element "+b.id+", check the '"+e.method+"' method.",j),j}}if(!h)return this.objectLength(f)&&this.successList.push(b),!0},customDataMessage:function(b,c){return a(b).data("msg"+c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.substring(1).toLowerCase())||a(b).data("msg")},customMessage:function(a,b){var c=this.settings.messages[a];return c&&(c.constructor===String?c:c[b])},findDefined:function(){for(var a=0;a<arguments.length;a++)if(void 0!==arguments[a])return arguments[a];return void 0},defaultMessage:function(b,c){return this.findDefined(this.customMessage(b.name,c),this.customDataMessage(b,c),!this.settings.ignoreTitle&&b.title||void 0,a.validator.messages[c],"<strong>Warning: No message defined for "+b.name+"</strong>")},formatAndAdd:function(b,c){var d=this.defaultMessage(b,c.method),e=/\$?\{(\d+)\}/g;"function"==typeof d?d=d.call(this,c.parameters,b):e.test(d)&&(d=a.validator.format(d.replace(e,"{$1}"),c.parameters)),this.errorList.push({message:d,element:b,method:c.method}),this.errorMap[b.name]=d,this.submitted[b.name]=d},addWrapper:function(a){return this.settings.wrapper&&(a=a.add(a.parent(this.settings.wrapper))),a},defaultShowErrors:function(){var a,b,c;for(a=0;this.errorList[a];a++)c=this.errorList[a],this.settings.highlight&&this.settings.highlight.call(this,c.element,this.settings.errorClass,this.settings.validClass),this.showLabel(c.element,c.message);if(this.errorList.length&&(this.toShow=this.toShow.add(this.containers)),this.settings.success)for(a=0;this.successList[a];a++)this.showLabel(this.successList[a]);if(this.settings.unhighlight)for(a=0,b=this.validElements();b[a];a++)this.settings.unhighlight.call(this,b[a],this.settings.errorClass,this.settings.validClass);this.toHide=this.toHide.not(this.toShow),this.hideErrors(),this.addWrapper(this.toShow).show()},validElements:function(){return this.currentElements.not(this.invalidElements())},invalidElements:function(){return a(this.errorList).map(function(){return this.element})},showLabel:function(b,c){var d,e,f,g=this.errorsFor(b),h=this.idOrName(b),i=a(b).attr("aria-describedby");g.length?(g.removeClass(this.settings.validClass).addClass(this.settings.errorClass),g.html(c)):(g=a("<"+this.settings.errorElement+">").attr("id",h+"-error").addClass(this.settings.errorClass).html(c||""),d=g,this.settings.wrapper&&(d=g.hide().show().wrap("<"+this.settings.wrapper+"/>").parent()),this.labelContainer.length?this.labelContainer.append(d):this.settings.errorPlacement?this.settings.errorPlacement(d,a(b)):d.insertAfter(b),g.is("label")?g.attr("for",h):0===g.parents("label[for='"+h+"']").length&&(f=g.attr("id"),i?i.match(new RegExp("\b"+f+"\b"))||(i+=" "+f):i=f,a(b).attr("aria-describedby",i),e=this.groups[b.name],e&&a.each(this.groups,function(b,c){c===e&&a("[name='"+b+"']",this.currentForm).attr("aria-describedby",g.attr("id"))}))),!c&&this.settings.success&&(g.text(""),"string"==typeof this.settings.success?g.addClass(this.settings.success):this.settings.success(g,b)),this.toShow=this.toShow.add(g)},errorsFor:function(b){var c=this.idOrName(b),d=a(b).attr("aria-describedby"),e="label[for='"+c+"'], label[for='"+c+"'] *";return d&&(e=e+", #"+d.replace(/\s+/g,", #")),this.errors().filter(e)},idOrName:function(a){return this.groups[a.name]||(this.checkable(a)?a.name:a.id||a.name)},validationTargetFor:function(a){return this.checkable(a)&&(a=this.findByName(a.name).not(this.settings.ignore)[0]),a},checkable:function(a){return/radio|checkbox/i.test(a.type)},findByName:function(b){return a(this.currentForm).find("[name='"+b+"']")},getLength:function(b,c){switch(c.nodeName.toLowerCase()){case"select":return a("option:selected",c).length;case"input":if(this.checkable(c))return this.findByName(c.name).filter(":checked").length}return b.length},depend:function(a,b){return this.dependTypes[typeof a]?this.dependTypes[typeof a](a,b):!0},dependTypes:{"boolean":function(a){return a},string:function(b,c){return!!a(b,c.form).length},"function":function(a,b){return a(b)}},optional:function(b){var c=this.elementValue(b);return!a.validator.methods.required.call(this,c,b)&&"dependency-mismatch"},startRequest:function(a){this.pending[a.name]||(this.pendingRequest++,this.pending[a.name]=!0)},stopRequest:function(b,c){this.pendingRequest--,this.pendingRequest<0&&(this.pendingRequest=0),delete this.pending[b.name],c&&0===this.pendingRequest&&this.formSubmitted&&this.form()?(a(this.currentForm).submit(),this.formSubmitted=!1):!c&&0===this.pendingRequest&&this.formSubmitted&&(a(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form",[this]),this.formSubmitted=!1)},previousValue:function(b){return a.data(b,"previousValue")||a.data(b,"previousValue",{old:null,valid:!0,message:this.defaultMessage(b,"remote")})}},classRuleSettings:{required:{required:!0},email:{email:!0},url:{url:!0},date:{date:!0},dateISO:{dateISO:!0},number:{number:!0},direccion:{direccion:!0},texto:{texto:!0},digits:{digits:!0},creditcard:{creditcard:!0}},addClassRules:function(b,c){b.constructor===String?this.classRuleSettings[b]=c:a.extend(this.classRuleSettings,b)},classRules:function(b){var c={},d=a(b).attr("class");return d&&a.each(d.split(" "),function(){this in a.validator.classRuleSettings&&a.extend(c,a.validator.classRuleSettings[this])}),c},attributeRules:function(b){var c,d,e={},f=a(b),g=b.getAttribute("type");for(c in a.validator.methods)"required"===c?(d=b.getAttribute(c),""===d&&(d=!0),d=!!d):d=f.attr(c),/min|max/.test(c)&&(null===g||/number|range|text/.test(g))&&(d=Number(d)),d||0===d?e[c]=d:g===c&&"range"!==g&&(e[c]=!0);return e.maxlength&&/-1|2147483647|524288/.test(e.maxlength)&&delete e.maxlength,e},dataRules:function(b){var c,d,e={},f=a(b);for(c in a.validator.methods)d=f.data("rule"+c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.substring(1).toLowerCase()),void 0!==d&&(e[c]=d);return e},staticRules:function(b){var c={},d=a.data(b.form,"validator");return d.settings.rules&&(c=a.validator.normalizeRule(d.settings.rules[b.name])||{}),c},normalizeRules:function(b,c){return a.each(b,function(d,e){if(e===!1)return void delete b[d];if(e.param||e.depends){var f=!0;switch(typeof e.depends){case"string":f=!!a(e.depends,c.form).length;break;case"function":f=e.depends.call(c,c)}f?b[d]=void 0!==e.param?e.param:!0:delete b[d]}}),a.each(b,function(d,e){b[d]=a.isFunction(e)?e(c):e}),a.each(["minlength","maxlength"],function(){b[this]&&(b[this]=Number(b[this]))}),a.each(["rangelength","range"],function(){var c;b[this]&&(a.isArray(b[this])?b[this]=[Number(b[this][0]),Number(b[this][1])]:"string"==typeof b[this]&&(c=b[this].replace(/[\[\]]/g,"").split(/[\s,]+/),b[this]=[Number(c[0]),Number(c[1])]))}),a.validator.autoCreateRanges&&(b.min&&b.max&&(b.range=[b.min,b.max],delete b.min,delete b.max),b.minlength&&b.maxlength&&(b.rangelength=[b.minlength,b.maxlength],delete b.minlength,delete b.maxlength)),b},normalizeRule:function(b){if("string"==typeof b){var c={};a.each(b.split(/\s/),function(){c[this]=!0}),b=c}return b},addMethod:function(b,c,d){a.validator.methods[b]=c,a.validator.messages[b]=void 0!==d?d:a.validator.messages[b],c.length<3&&a.validator.addClassRules(b,a.validator.normalizeRule(b))},methods:{required:function(b,c,d){if(!this.depend(d,c))return"dependency-mismatch";if("select"===c.nodeName.toLowerCase()){var e=a(c).val();return e&&e.length>0}return this.checkable(c)?this.getLength(b,c)>0:a.trim(b).length>0},email:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(a)},url:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^(https?|s?ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(a)},date:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(a).toString())},dateISO:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^\d{4}[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/.test(a)},number:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(a)},direccion:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^[A-Za-z0-9\#\-\s\xF1\xD1\xC1\xC9\xCD\xBF\xDA\xE1\xE9\xED\xF3\xFA]+$/.test(a)},texto:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^[A-Za-z\s\xF1\xD1\xC1\xC9\xCD\xBF\xDA\xE1\xE9\xED\xF3\xFA]+$/.test(a)},digits:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^\d+$/.test(a)},creditcard:function(a,b){if(this.optional(b))return"dependency-mismatch";if(/[^0-9 \-]+/.test(a))return!1;var c,d,e=0,f=0,g=!1;if(a=a.replace(/\D/g,""),a.length<13||a.length>19)return!1;for(c=a.length-1;c>=0;c--)d=a.charAt(c),f=parseInt(d,10),g&&(f*=2)>9&&(f-=9),e+=f,g=!g;return e%10===0},minlength:function(b,c,d){var e=a.isArray(b)?b.length:this.getLength(a.trim(b),c);return this.optional(c)||e>=d},maxlength:function(b,c,d){var e=a.isArray(b)?b.length:this.getLength(a.trim(b),c);return this.optional(c)||d>=e},rangelength:function(b,c,d){var e=a.isArray(b)?b.length:this.getLength(a.trim(b),c);return this.optional(c)||e>=d[0]&&e<=d[1]},min:function(a,b,c){return this.optional(b)||a>=c},max:function(a,b,c){return this.optional(b)||c>=a},range:function(a,b,c){return this.optional(b)||a>=c[0]&&a<=c[1]},equalTo:function(b,c,d){var e=a(d);return this.settings.onfocusout&&e.unbind(".validate-equalTo").bind("blur.validate-equalTo",function(){a(c).valid()}),b===e.val()},remote:function(b,c,d){if(this.optional(c))return"dependency-mismatch";var e,f,g=this.previousValue(c);return this.settings.messages[c.name]||(this.settings.messages[c.name]={}),g.originalMessage=this.settings.messages[c.name].remote,this.settings.messages[c.name].remote=g.message,d="string"==typeof d&&{url:d}||d,g.old===b?g.valid:(g.old=b,e=this,this.startRequest(c),f={},f[c.name]=b,a.ajax(a.extend(!0,{url:d,mode:"abort",port:"validate"+c.name,dataType:"json",data:f,context:e.currentForm,success:function(d){var f,h,i,j=d===!0||"true"===d;e.settings.messages[c.name].remote=g.originalMessage,j?(i=e.formSubmitted,e.prepareElement(c),e.formSubmitted=i,e.successList.push(c),delete e.invalid[c.name],e.showErrors()):(f={},h=d||e.defaultMessage(c,"remote"),f[c.name]=g.message=a.isFunction(h)?h(b):h,e.invalid[c.name]=!0,e.showErrors(f)),g.valid=j,e.stopRequest(c,j)}},d)),"pending")}}}),a.format=function(){throw"$.format has been deprecated. Please use $.validator.format instead."};var b,c={};a.ajaxPrefilter?a.ajaxPrefilter(function(a,b,d){var e=a.port;"abort"===a.mode&&(c[e]&&c[e].abort(),c[e]=d)}):(b=a.ajax,a.ajax=function(d){var e=("mode"in d?d:a.ajaxSettings).mode,f=("port"in d?d:a.ajaxSettings).port;return"abort"===e?(c[f]&&c[f].abort(),c[f]=b.apply(this,arguments),c[f]):b.apply(this,arguments)}),a.extend(a.fn,{validateDelegate:function(b,c,d){return this.bind(c,function(c){var e=a(c.target);return e.is(b)?d.apply(e,arguments):void 0})}})});
```

Comment: Andres, intenta publicar un ejemplo que se pueda reproducir tu error para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ok. Ya lo hago.

Comment: No pongas el código del plugin, pon el código HTML y el JS donde se activa el plugin (si no es automático).

Answer (score 0):

no se porque sucede eso, en mi caso no utilizo Required, para validar que un campo no quedase en blanco, lo que hago es lo siguiente:

Ejm. tenemos los campos: primer nombre y segundo nombre, primer nombre es el primer campo del formulario, segundo nombre es el segundo, si primer nombre esta en blanco y hago click en segundo nombre, este se bloquea, y aparece un mensaje diciendo que primer nombre  no puede quedar en blanco, por lo que solo me deja escribir en el campo primer nombre.

Si no solucionas el error podrías hacer algo como eso, te dejo un ejemplo es un javascript:

```
     $("#pnombre_usu").focusout(function(){

            if($("#pnombre_usu").val().length<1){

                $("#pnombre_usu").addClass("blanco");

                $("#msg_pn").removeClass("hide");

                       window.document.r_usuarios.pnombre_usu.focus();      
                       window.document.r_usuarios.pnombre_usu.select();     
                       return false;    
                }

              return true;
          });

         $("#pnombre_usu").keypress(function(){
         $("#pnombre_usu").removeClass("blanco");
          $("#msg_pn").addClass("hide");


         });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código en el Formulario

```
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label>Primer Nombre</label>
               <input type="text" id="pnombre_usu" name="pnombre_usu" class="form-control" placeholder="Marcela">
                <span class="hide" id="msg_pn" style="color:red;">Este campo no puede quedar en blanco</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```