# Cambiar posicion de un mensaje de error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente codigo HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <span class="has-float-label">
<input style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px" class="form-control required digits" id="numero" name="numero" type="text" placeholder="   " tabindex=2/>
<label style="font-family:Arial; font-size:13px" for="numero">Número Identificación *</label>
</span>
</div>
```

El imput y el label estan dentro del span con la clase "has-float-label", porque quiero que me haga el efecto que se ve en la imagen (QUe cuando selecciono el texbox el titulo sube):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como los texbox tienen "Requiered" que me valida que los campos no esten vacios, me muestra lo siguiente cuando le doy al boton aceptar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero esque ese mensaje de error me lo muestre de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el HTML encontre esta parte del codigo:

```js
.validate({
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  element.after(error);
},
rules: {
  confirm: {
    equalTo: "#numero"
  }
}
});
});
```

Y cambie before por after pero me lo coloca asi el mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto esta en bootstrap, yo pienso que debo decirle que el mensaje de error me lo coloque despues del grupo  pero es eso lo que no se hacer.

Comment: [Has preguntado la misma pregunta 2 veces](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103545/ayuda-con-el-placeholder-y-label-float) deberias de eliminar 1 de las dos.

Comment: juega con el _HTML_, cambia el elemento **span** por un **div**, o puede que añadiendo un **br** al final del **input** ...